# Thrift Build stopped with "src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.cpp:43:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found"

Tags: python-2.7, thrift, macos-mojave

I was trying to install thrift(0.11.0) over my system(macOs 10.14.5).For which I downloaded and extracted tar file. Then I ran following commands :

```
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

while execution of **make**, I got following error :

```
src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.cpp:43:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
```

I tried installing openssl and cryptography and they were already upto date.

Any advice on what I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on macos, I assume that openssl headers are installed using Homebrew. If not, install them like this:

`brew install openssl`

However, the library headers themselves will still not be in the system's usual `/usr/include` directory. Therefore to add the headers in brew to the system's default include directory that will be searched by most compilers, try this:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ /usr/include/`

This worked for me when I encountered the same issue when installing some pypy pip requirements.